# java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:

Tags: chisel

```js
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error]  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[error]  at chisel3.core.assert$.apply(Assert.scala:76)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.setupVerilatorBackend$.apply(VerilatorBackend.scala:262)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:56)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at logger.Logger$$anonfun$makeScope$1.apply(Logger.scala:138)
[error]  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[error]  at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:136)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:38)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:100)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$.delayedEndpoint$mnist$FC2Main$1(FC2Main.scala:8)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$delayedInit$body.apply(FC2Main.scala:7)
[error]  at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
[error]  at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
[error]  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]  at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
[error]  at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$.main(FC2Main.scala:7)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main.main(FC2Main.scala)
[error]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Test / runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 20041 s, completed Jan 15, 2019 3:04:24 AM
```

[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:

This error shows up when I was trying to run a big Chisel program. If the calculation of the program is smaller, it doesn't show up.
Basically, my code calculates the multiplications of a few matrices.

I increased the sbt memory to the most and deleted the temporary files before running the code.

Comment: Can you provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error]  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[error]  at chisel3.core.assert$.apply(Assert.scala:76)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.setupVerilatorBackend$.apply(VerilatorBackend.scala:262)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:56)

Comment: [error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at logger.Logger$$anonfun$makeScope$1.apply(Logger.scala:138)
[error]  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[error]  at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:136)

Comment: [error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:39)
[error]  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:38)
[error]  at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:100)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$.delayedEndpoint$mnist$FC2Main$1(FC2Main.scala:8)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$delayedInit$body.apply(FC2Main.scala:7)

Comment: [error]  at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
[error]  at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
[error]  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]  at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
[error]  at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
[error]  at mnist.FC2Main$.main(FC2Main.scala:7)

Comment: [error]  at mnist.FC2Main.main(FC2Main.scala)
[error]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Test / runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 20041 s, completed Jan 15, 2019 3:04:24 AM

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could put the stack trace into your original post as an edit like so:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:
[error] at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[error] at chisel3.core.assert$.apply(Assert.scala:76)
[error] at chisel3.iotesters.setupVerilatorBackend$.apply(VerilatorBackend.scala:262)
[error] at chisel3.iotesters.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Driver.scala:56)
```

In any case, it's pointing to this line: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers/blob/8a737012f3c93dd41a3a9e120eebfc07ba541ebf/src/main/scala/chisel3/iotesters/VerilatorBackend.scala#L262

That suggests to me that the Verilator compilation is failing. Do you have other stuff being printed? Perhaps something like:
`/bin/sh: 1: verilator: not found`

If that is the case, then you don't have `verilator` installed, here are the instructions for Linux: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3#ubuntu-like-linux

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My Verilator works in other programs. These are all the errors printed.

Comment: Hi jkoenig, I installed the verilator again, now it seems working well. Thank you for your advice!